# Web config vs In-memory tables/memory optimized tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, memory-optimized-tables

In my web.config file for an ASP.NET web application, I have around 150 key-value pairs under `<appsettings>`. Should I convert this web.config file into an In-Memory table / Memory optimized table of SQL Server? Will I get any performance increase?
There will be no write operation on the web.config file

Answer (score 1):

No, you will be making calls across the network to get the values from SQL Server, just leave them there.